# libcurl specifying the header

Tags: c++, qt, curl

I am currently using pre-compiled minGW32 libraries for *libcurl-7.21.6*, C++, QT libraries, minGW32 windows compiler (in QT creator) and QT creator as my IDE.
I am trying to post some http information but keep running into a problem. I need to remove *Expect: 100...* from my header. From everything i have seen online,

```
headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Expect:");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
```

should do it, but it seems to get nullified by:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);
```

If i call the *HTTPPOST* before the *HTTPHEADER*, it seems like the *HTTPHEADER* nullifies everything from the *HTTPPOST*, and vice versa.

Am I doing something wrong? Should the *Expect:* be somehow included in the HTTPPOST instead of separately in HTTPHEADER?
I am trying to get rid of the *Expect* header because the server keeps responding to my request with *Expectation Failed*.

Here is the curl command used with *curl.exe* to do the samething i'm trying to do with libcurl:

```
system("curl --referer http://192.168.16.23/upthefile.html -F uploadfile=@instructions.xml -F config=on http://192.168.16.23/cgi-bin/upload.cgi -H \"Expect:\">nul");
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *cURL 7.25.0* and this snippet:

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

struct curl_httppost *formpost = NULL;
struct curl_httppost *lastptr = NULL;
struct curl_slist *headerlist = curl_slist_append(NULL, "Expect:");

curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "field", CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "value", CURLFORM_END);
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

if (curl)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);

    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_formfree(formpost);
    curl_slist_free_all(headerlist);
}
```

I obtain the following request (Wireshark'd):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 145
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------523d686b5061
------------------------------523d686b5061
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field"
value
------------------------------523d686b5061--
```

While omitting the line `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);` the header contains also:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

Comment: Hmm, i tried everything but was still having problems. I'm going to reinstall the IDE and see if it help. THanks for the help

Comment: Instead of reinstalling the IDE, try compiling the smallest example which can reproduce the problem, and start from there

Comment: Apologies for the super late response. Your suggestion worked great!!  One thing for anyone else playing with curl is to watch out for the timeout in single threaded applications.

Comment: Thank you! This was the most annoying thing to track down.